# I am Vashishtha Brahmin by Gotra but I don't know my shakha .I live in Bijnor Uttar Pradesh

Tags: dharma

I want to know the shakha of my Gotra. I am vashistha by Gotra. There is no elder one here in my family. How can I know.

Comment: All Brahmins from UP follow Mādhyandina śākhā of Śuklayajurveda.

Comment: Can you tell me all the shakhas that are followed by Brahmins? If we are to get our children married how I will come to know.

Comment: Gotra and Shakha are completely irrelevant topics. Gotra and Pravara are associated with each other and Veda and Shaka also with each other but those two groups are entirely different.

Comment: Sometimes when we want to get married our children in the same gotra , suggested option we find in shakha. That's why I was asking .

Comment: Marrying in the same gotra is prohibited. Sex with a sagotra is a sin more severe than the mahapatakas, according to Vishnusmriti.

Comment: All north Indian brahmins follow Mādhyandina śākhā of Śuklayajurveda while all South Indians mostly follow Taittirīya śākhā of Kṛṣṇayajurveda. In Eastern India (Bengali, Maithili, Odiya & Assamese), Kauṭhuma śākhā of Sāmaveda & Kāṇva śākhā of Śuklayajurveda are prevalent. In Telegu & Tamil society, Rāṇayanīya śākhā of Sāmaveda is prevalent. In Kerala, Jaiminīya śākhā of Sāmaveda is prevalent alongside Śākala śākhā of Ṛgveda. Kaśmīri panḍits follow the Kaṭha-Kapiṣṭhala śākhā of Kṛṣṇayajurveda. A section of Deśastha brahmins & some Bengali brahmins follow the Āśvalāyana śākhā of Ṛgveda.

Comment: Śaunakīya śākhā of Atharvaveda is followed by some Nāgara brahmins of Gujarat while the Paippalāda śākhā is followed by some Utkala brahmins.

Comment: Ask the older members of your family who might know about this stuff which Veda your clan belongs to. If it's Yajurveda then It'd be pretty obvious that you are a Mādhyandina śākhin. If it's not it'd be more complicated.

Comment: @অনু All brahmins from UP following shukla yajurveda is wrong, The most common veda among Kanyakubja brahmins by gotra is the saama veda kauthumna shakha